# Django | No muestra contenido de DetailView

Tags: python, django

No me muestra el contenido de detail view, simplemente se muestra el título "Detalle evento de limpieza en calendario".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**models.py**

```
class EventTankCleaning(models.Model):
    installation_TankCleaning = models.ForeignKey(Installation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    startdatetime_TankCleaning = models.DateField('Fecha y hora de comienzo de limpieza', null=True, blank=True)
    observations_TankCleaning = models.TextField('Observaciones', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Añadir limpieza de tanque'
        verbose_name = 'Añadir limpiezas de tanques'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.installation_TankCleaning)
```

**urls.py**

```
path(
        'detail_eventTankCleaning/<pk>/',
        views.DetailEventTankCleaning.as_view(),
        name='detail_eventTankCleaning',
    ),
```

**view.py**

```
class DetailEventTankCleaning(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = EventTankCleaning
    template_name = "cleaning/detail_cleaning.html"
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')
```

**detail_cleaning.html**

```
div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-lg-0 col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="alert border m-3 bg-light" role="alert">
                <h3 class="text-dark">Detalle evento de limpieza en calendario</h3>

{{ installation_TankCleaning }}
{{ startdatetime_TankCleaning }}
{{ observations_TankCleaning }}
                        
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offser-lg-0 col-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error sucede por que solo pones en el template el campo del objeto installation_TankCleaning, startdatetime_TankCleaning  y observations_TankCleaning  pero no el contexto que lleva el objeto. Por defecto se regresa el contexto 'object' para poder acceder a los campos del objeto. Se hace de esta manera:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-lg-0 col-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="alert border m-3 bg-light" role="alert">
                <h3 class="text-dark">Detalle evento de limpieza en calendario</h3>

{{ object.installation_TankCleaning }}
{{ object.startdatetime_TankCleaning }}
{{ object.observations_TankCleaning }}
                        
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offser-lg-0 col-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver a detalle esto en la función get_context_data() de DetailView aquí: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get_context_data

Comment: Así es. Muchas gracias.